# Setting lists margins in html2pdf

Tags: html2pdf

I need to render very long list (rules) so I need to get rid of margins.

How can I set margins of lists in `pdf2html` ?
`ul {padding:0; margin:0;} li {padding:0; margin:0;}` is not working:/

Answer (score 0):

You can save some pixels setting [Document Margin](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/doc/page.md#margin-explanation) like this:

```
$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf("P", "A4", "en", TRUE, "UTF-8", array(0,0,0,0));
```

But, if you need your list very tight/well-compressed, set a negative padding to li:

```
li {
    padding-top:-4px;
}
```

I hope this helps someone.